# How to get the first text node from a string?

Tags: jquery

Trying to get the very first text node.

```
var s = $.trim('login<tbody> <tr> <td class="translated">Lorem ipsum dummy text</td></tr><tr><td class="translated">This is a new paragraph</td></tr><tr><td class="translated"><b>Email</b></td></tr><tr><td><i>This is yet another text</i></td> </tr></tbody>');

if($(s).find('*').andSelf().not('b,i').length > 1){
    alert($(s).find('*:not(:empty)').first().text());
}
```

[Here is a link to what i am doing on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNp84/)

It is not giving me the very first text node which is **"login"** rather it is givig me
**"lorem ipsum..."** which is 2nd text node.

**NOTE:**

The HTML string is dynamic so do not think of assigning class or id to it or enclosing it in some HTML element or substring etc.

Comment: So what's the issue with what you're doing right now?

Comment: mind if I ask, is it possible to contain broke tags like this: `html>blah blah blah</html>`?

Comment: @JonathanChow ! no it will not contain any broken tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML is already a string, I would just use `substring()` to get all characters leading up to the first angled bracket:

```
var s = $.trim('login<tbody> <tr> <td class="translated">Lorem ipsum dummy text</td></tr><tr><td class="translated">This is a new paragraph</td></tr><tr><td class="translated"><b>Email</b></td></tr><tr><td><i>This is yet another text</i></td> </tr></tbody>');

s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<'));
// "login"
```

**Update**

This will find the first text node if it's not at the beginning or `undefined` if there are no text nodes:

```
$(s).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3 })[0]
```

**Update 2**

This could also work, though I haven't looked closely at the repercussions of doing it:

```
$(s).find('*').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3})[0]
```

Comment: thanks for replying but this string is just example, it may not be the case everytime mean there may not be the text node at this position always.

Comment: @atif this will work for any situation where the "login" for example is not contained in an element in the string.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst what if i want to bypass some tags like <b>,<i>,<span> etc ?